# Make a video fit in a TextureView (Parts of it are outside (not visible)) using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video, scale, textureview

I'm using a MediaPlayer to play videos in a TextureView.
The TextureView has a fixed size, and the videos' sizes are different.
It plays the videos, but the problem is parts of the video are outside and the video isn't scaled down to fit the TextureView.

The black rectangles + the photo (video) are the TextureView.
The red rectangle is the actual video, I drew it ofcourse to show the problem.

So it only shows a part of the video and not showing the rest of it.

I want all the video to be visible and keep it's original scale-ratio.

Thanks.

[image]

```
// The class implements SurfaceTextureListener 

// Set TextureView to MediaPlayer
m_TextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
    m_MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    m_MediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(surfaceTexture));
}

// Play video
m_MediaPlayer.reset();
m_MediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoFilePath);
m_MediaPlayer.prepare();
m_MediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: show what you've done so far

Comment: pskink - added a little code, nothing special about it.

Comment: did you try setTransform?

Comment: For an example, see `adjustAspectRatio()` in Grafika's video player (currently https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java#L214).

Comment: The result of using AdjustAspectRatio(m_MediaPlayer.getVideoWidth(), m_MediaPlayer.getVideoHeight()); : 1) the video's size on screen remains the same. 2) more of the video is visible. so it means it damages the aspect-ratio (my drawn red rectengle now lost height, more is visible with a bad aspect ratio). I also tried to play with the width-height parameters, best result is getting all the video visible but with even worse aspect-ratio.

Comment: I've been trying so many things, resize the TextureView, setTransform (using adjustAspectRatio()) .. 3 days sitting on this :( is there a way to make the video fit the TextureView's width and height ?

Comment: We used the getRotationMatrix sample code from http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=249763 to solve the rotation/translation calculations for us, since it can be quite confusing trying to figure it out on your own.